# Filterable Portfolio Hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, portfolio

I'm working with a filterable Portfolio. I've got a little problem with the links to filter the portfolio.

When I click on the buttons, it filters the portfolio correctly, but after that it connects automatically to the a site like xy.com/#myfilter and trying to open it.

Maybe you have an idea how to disable this?

**LINK SAMPLE:**

```
<a href="#design" rel="design">Design</a>
```

**THE JS-FILE IS THE FOLLOWING:**

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.filterable = function(settings) {
    settings = $.extend({
      useHash          : true,
      animationSpeed   : 500,
      show             : { width: 'show', opacity: 'show' },
      hide             : { width: 'hide', opacity: 'hide' },
      useTags          : true,
      tagSelector      : '#portfolio-filter a',
      selectedTagClass : 'current',
      allTag           : 'all'
    }, settings);

    return $(this).each(function(){

      /* FILTER: select a tag and filter */
      $(this).bind("filter", function( e, tagToShow ){
        if(settings.useTags){
          $(settings.tagSelector)
            .removeClass(settings.selectedTagClass);
          $(settings.tagSelector + '[href=' + tagToShow + ']')
            .addClass(settings.selectedTagClass);
        }

        $(this).trigger("filterportfolio", [ tagToShow.substr(1) ]);
      });

      /* FILTERPORTFOLIO: pass in a class to show, all others will be hidden */
      $(this).bind("filterportfolio", function( e, classToShow ){
        if(classToShow == settings.allTag){
          $(this).trigger("show");
        }else{
          $(this).trigger("show", [ '.' + classToShow ] );
          $(this).trigger("hide", [ ':not(.' + classToShow + ')' ] );
        }

        if(settings.useHash){
          location.hash = '#' + classToShow;
        }
      });

      /* SHOW: show a single class*/
      $(this).bind("show", function( e, selectorToShow ){  
        $(this)
          .children(selectorToShow)
          .animate(settings.show, settings.animationSpeed);
      });

      /* SHOW: hide a single class*/
      $(this).bind("hide", function( e, selectorToHide ){
        $(this)
          .children(selectorToHide)
          .animate(settings.hide, settings.animationSpeed); 
      });

      /* ============ Check URL Hash ====================*/
      if(settings.useHash){
        if(location.hash != '') {
          $(this).trigger("filter", [ location.hash ]);
        }else{
          $(this).trigger("filter", [ '#' + settings.allTag ]);
        }

        /* ============ Setup Tags ====================*/
        if(settings.useTags){
          $(settings.tagSelector).click(function(){
            $('#portfolio-list').trigger("filter", [ $(this).attr('href') ]);
            $(settings.tagSelector).removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
          });
        }
      });
    }
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#portfolio-list').filterable();

});
```

Could it also be, that I have a problem with my search friendly URLS?
Thanks a lot for every help.

Best regards.

Comment: The `a` does not have any script associated with it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some adjustments to the click event:

**At your current click function:**

```
$(settings.tagSelector).click(function(){
  $('#portfolio-list').trigger("filter", [ $(this).attr('href') ]);

  $(settings.tagSelector).removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

**Change it to:**

```
$(settings.tagSelector).click(function(event){
  $('#portfolio-list').trigger("filter", [ $(this).attr('href') ]);

  $(settings.tagSelector).removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');

  // push the hash into the url
  location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

  // stop the regular href
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

This allows you to place the hash value into the URL, but prevent the browser from actually reloading the page with that hash when the user clicks the link!

---

**Read more about it:**

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)  |  [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: If that did solve your problem, tick the answer to close this topic! Ps: Glad I could help!